Kestrel is not starting on AKS
I've migrated an application from .NET 3.1 to .NET8.
Running it on my machine works fine, even if i define it to run in http or a docker context.
The problem is that Kestrel never starts when running this application on Managed Kubernetes Service (AKS).
I already set the kestrel configuration on Appsettings.json, and there isn't no overrides on AppSettings.Staging.json.
I enable all the trace logs to see if i could discover something.
Appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "*": "Trace"
    }
  },

  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:80"
      },
      "gRPC": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:81",
        "Protocols": "Http2"
      }
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Program.cs:
public class Program
{
    public static readonly string Namespace = typeof(Startup).Namespace!;

    public static readonly string AppName = Namespace[(Namespace.LastIndexOf('.', Namespace.LastIndexOf('.') - 1) + 1)..];

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Program"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    protected Program()
    {
    }

    public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        ILogger<Program> logger = null;
        try
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
            logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogInformation("Starting web host ({ApplicationContext})...", Program.AppName);
            await host.RunAsync();

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger?.LogError(ex, "Program terminated unexpectedly ({ApplicationContext})!", Program.AppName);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .CaptureStartupErrors(false)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
               {
                   builder.AddSerilog();
               });
}


Starup Configure Method:
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IWebHostEnvironment env,
    IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider,
    VeredasDbContext dbContext,
    IAuditInjector auditInjector)
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
        builder.WithExposedHeaders("X-Authorization-Token");
    });

    app.UseWhen(
        context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/hc"),
        appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseApiLogMiddleware();
            appBuilder.UseRenewableAuthTokenMiddleware();
        });

    if (!env.IsEnvironment("IntegrationTest"))
    {
        app.UseSwaggerConfig(provider, env);

        // Apply migration if necessary
        using var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
        dbContext.ApplyMigrations();
        auditInjector.Inject(dbContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseJwt();

    app.ConfigureLocalization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<GrpcServices.ProcessService>();
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<GrpcServices.FundService>();

        if (!CurrentEnvironment.IsEnvironment("IntegrationTest"))
        {
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/hc", new HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                Predicate = _ => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
            });
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/readiness", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = r => r.Name.Contains("self"),
            });
        }
    });

    this.Logger.LogInformation("Done");
}

When app start to run, i got these logs below:
info: MyApp.Api.Startup[0]
      Done
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10407]
      'MyDbContext' disposed.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20007]
      Disposing connection to database 'db_staging' on server ''.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20008]
      Disposed connection to database 'db_staging' on server '' (0ms).
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[62]
      User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.

We can see that there is a "Done" in the logs, which means that the app passed onto it.
But, it never shows a log like this:
Hosting environment: Staging
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:81
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:80

Looks like the app never starts the Kestrel.
For some reason the Kestrel is not starting in this enviroment and i can't figure out why it is happening. Do you guys have some idea what it could be?

It's a guess, but if not hosted through IIS, I think you have to set the urls manually like this. So either set the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable, urls configuration, or UseUrls method

I already following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-endpoints-in-appsettingsjson

Ah i forgot to mention: Microsoft changed the default port from 80 to 8080 in .NET 7/8. So that would explain why it stopped working after your upgrade. Just set the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable to use port 80 again

@BrunoWarmling Did you ever go past this problem? what was the solution?

@JuanP.Garces it worked running like this: WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().UseKestrel();

@BrunoWarmling Could you provide a copy of your Program.cs and Startup? .UseKestrel() did not work for me and I fear I am missing something obvious

@JuanP.Garces sure, you can get them here
